# How to fetch latest association with complex primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need to map make @OneToMany association as one entity (@ManyToOne or @OneToOne) which has the latest field

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "trips")
public class TripEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "trips_sequence")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "trips_sequence",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "trips_seq"),
                    @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "100"),
                    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            })
    @Column(name = "trip_id")
    private Long id;

    //Initially it was such mapping:
    //@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "trip", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //private Set<TripTelemetryEntity> tripTelemetry = new HashSet<>();

   //Finally I need something like this
   //@ManyToOne or @OneToOne
   private TripTelemetryEntity lastTripTelemetry;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(TripTelemetryEntity.TripTelemetryId.class)
@Table(name = "trip_telemetry")
public class    TripTelemetryEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "trip_id")
    private Long tripId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "trip_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TripEntity trip;

    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "occurred_on")
    private Date occurredOn;

    @Override
    public TripTelemetryId getId() {
        return new TripTelemetryId(tripId, occurredOn);
    }

    /**
     * This represents a "composite primary key" for the trip_telemetry table.
     */
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class TripTelemetryId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected Long tripId;

        protected Date occurredOn;

    }
}
```

if I add

```java
@JoinFormula("(SELECT r.id FROM trip_telemetry r WHERE r.trip_id = trip_id ORDER BY r.occurred_on DESC LIMIT 1)")
```

so I catch exception:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.app.core.domain.TripTelemetryEntity from com.app.core.domain.TripEntity has the wrong number of column. should be 2*

If I do so:

```java
     @ManyToOne
     @Where(clause = "occurred_on = now()")
    private TripTelemetryEntity tripTelemetry;
```

I catch exception:
*org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column tripentity0_.triptelemetry_occurred_on does not exist*